# Upload image in review section in opencart:2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

How can I make a section to upload images for products they purchased in review.
I hope it can be done with steps. I want to implement with this jquery UI https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

This helps me a lot to know about how to develop new things in opencart with MVC.
Thank you. this community really helps me to learn more.

Comment: Hi Anmol, this is something that is quite a detailed process and will require development not only to extend OpenCart but also develop the requisite module to handle the upload according to the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup), fortunately it has sample code. May I suggest looking at an extension?

Comment: Purpose is to learn how to embeds functionalities in opencart (MVC)framework. you can even tell how to add simple uploading in opencart review. you can even tell me the headings of steps need to implementing it.

Comment: And also you can suggest me the Extension.

Comment: I'll gladly share some useful steps but the actual work of integrating this plugin is another task altogether! Have a look at the OpenCart marketplace, I'm not sure what your needs are and so won't be able to search for you..

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question it seems you want to edit the current product review to include (or at least allow the inclusion - there's nothing about the photo being mandatory) photos for a review. This means altering:

**Front-end**

1. The display of existing reviews (`catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl`)
2. The edit form for creating reviews (`catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl`)
3. The controller action to display reviews (`catalog\controller\product\product.php` method `review()`)
4. The controller action to save reviews (`catalog\controller\product\product.php` method `write()`)
5. The database schema of the `oc_reviews` table to add a column that either stores a path to a single image or a foreign key to a table that has all review image paths stored
6. The model for retrieving reviews (`catalog\model\catalog\review.php` method `getReviewsByProductId()`)
7. The model for saving reviews (`catalog\model\catalog\review.php` method `addReview()`)

**Admin** (technically optional)

8. The admin list view of all existing reviews (`admin\view\catalog\review_list.tpl`)
9. The admin controller to view all existing reviews (`admin\controller\catalog\review.php` method `getList()`)
10. The model for retrieving reviews (`admin\model\catalog\review.php` method `getReview()`)
11. The admin view to display a single review (`admin\view\catalog\review_form.tpl`)
12. The admin controller action for display of a review (`admin\controller\catalog\review.php` method `getForm()`)
13. The model for retrieving a single review (`admin\model\catalog\review.php` method `addReview()`)
14. The admin controller action for edit of existing reviews
    (`admin\controller\catalog\review.php` method `edit()`)
15. The admin controller action for addition of reviews (`admin\controller\catalog\review.php` method `add()`)
16. The model for creating reviews (`admin\model\catalog\review.php` method `addReview()`)
17. The model for editing reviews (`admin\model\catalog\review.php` method `editReview()`)

Hopefully this will guide you on which files to modify although this is best done using OCMOD - if you're successful you could sell the OCMOD as an extension

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. I am working on it. and will ask you where i will stuck in process.

Comment: You're welcome @Anmolsingh you might need to add some of the php from the File-Upload plugin to the `catalog\controller\tool\upload.php`